# Customising xlviewer.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-2010, export-to-excel

I'm trying to customise the xlviewer.aspx page of SharePoint to remove the 'Open in Excel' button and potentially replace it with the 'Download a Snapshot', has anyone else tried to do this and made any progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following Javascript to xlviewer.aspx allowed me to remove the open in excel buttons

```
</script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        setTimeout(HideOpenInExcelRibbonButton, 10); 
    });

    function HideOpenInExcelRibbonButton()
    {
        $('a[id*="openInExcel"]').hide();  

         var doc = document.getElementsByTagName('ie:menuitem'); 

         for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++)
         {
          itm = doc[i];
          if (itm.id.match("OpenInExcel")!=null)
           { itm.hidden=true; }
         } 
        setTimeout(HideOpenInExcelRibbonButton, 10);
    }   
    </script>
```